# need help for Making Color switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a wordpress theme from html but I used some different components from html template for my theme.I must add color switch option for live with js or jquery and for stabil by php as a back-end language.

I miss some class names because of different components so I must detect them.

I wrote below code.When click color1 button, text color and background color changes to red as I want.But the problem is also my theme has buttons.The buttons has hover property for background color.When I use below code, the hover background color property removes and their background color changes to red while hover or not.

I want to save their hover properties.Also I want to notice that all of them are not button tag.Some of them only div tag but they seem as button on screen.

How can I do it? Also for the buttons have hover property, I can copy class names by hand because their number is only 3-5.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict"

    document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
        const color = style.getPropertyValue('color');
        const Bcolor = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');

        if (color === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {

            $("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("color", "red", "important");

                return false;
            });

        }
        
            if (Bcolor === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {

            $("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important");
                
                return false;
            });
        }
        
        
    });
    
        $("#color-style-switcher .bottom a.settings").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var div = $("#color-style-switcher");
            if (div.css("left") === "-195px") {
                $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
                    left: "0px"
                });
            } else {
                $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
                    left: "-195px"
                });
            }
        })

        $("ul.colors li a").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().parent().find("a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        })
});


jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" id="colors" href="http://hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/plugins/Hekim/widgets/css/colors/default.css" type="text/css" />');
jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/plugins/Hekim/widgets/css/color-switcher.css" type="text/css" />');
```

---

As a trying, I wrote below code but it didnt work.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ulockd-btn-white:hover, .ulockd-btn-white:active, .ulockd-btn-white:focus')
  .style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important");
```

---

the part of question until the now is for live color switcher function.Also I want to make stabil color switcher.So, I must save all of related class names.I will use the class names in php script.So how can I save the class names? Their form must be in  form.For example, .classname1, classname2, etc.

---

**Edit:**

Here is the target website: http://www.hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/

There is a color switcher on left of the screen.Click first color ( it is default selected color, please click on it ), some colors and background colors will change to red.

There is some buttons for example, `Explore Service`  button.The button has hover property normally  but when you click first color on color switcher, its background color changed to red and its hover property removes.Its background color changes to red while hover or not.

Comment: What "hover properties"? Could you please provide your HTML and CSS as well?

Comment: @hev1 I added it bottom of my question as edit